# How to Make Drag and Drop Quiz in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, drag-and-drop, create-react-app, draggable

hopefully we are all in good health wherever we are.
I have a problem when I want to create a Quiz with Drag and Drop type in React Native. I'm using the **react-native-drax library**. The data I use comes from **firebase**, if it is described as follows :

```
[{
    quest: "Book ?",
    options: ["Yes","No"],
    correct_option: "Yes",
    type:'yesorno',
    image:'urlofimages'
},
{
    quest: "Fill the following words  \n F_ _t Train M_ _ ern",
    options: ["as","od","am"],
    correct_option: ["as","od"],
    type:'drag',
    image:''
}]
```

(all quiz data is accommodated in the variable **allData**).

then I made the following components, to create a drag and drop area. I made it **dynamic**. **Dropzone** corresponds to the number of **correct_option** and **TouchDrag** corresponds to the number of options (taken from data).

```
import { DraxProvider, DraxView, DraxList } from 'react-native-drax';
....
.....
.......
const Exam = () => {
  const [showAnwOne, setAnwOne] = useState([]);
  const [showAnwTwo, setAnwTwo] = useState([]);
...
.....
.......
 
  const Draxzone= ({item,index}) =>{
    return(
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-around', width:'100%', marginBottom:20}}>
          <DraxView
              style={styles.receiver}
              key={item}
              receivingStyle={styles.receiving}
              onReceiveDragDrop={(event) => {
                  let selected_item = event.dragged.payload;
                  setAnwOne(selected_item)
              }}

          >
            <Text>{showAnwOne}</Text>
        </DraxView>
      </View>
    )
  }

  const TouchDrag = ({item,index})=>{
    return(
            <DraxView
                style={styles.draggable}
                draggingStyle={styles.dragging}
                dragReleasedStyle={styles.dragging}
                hoverDraggingStyle={styles.hoverDragging}
                dragPayload={index}
                longPressDelay={0}
                key={item}
            >
                <Text style={{color:'#FFF'}}>{item}</Text>
            </DraxView>
    )
  }
```

after that I display the component as follows:
(quiz is displayed based on its type)

```
{allData[currentIndex]?.type === 'drag' ?
    <DraxProvider>
       <View style={{width:'100%'}}>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-around', width:'100%', marginBottom:20}}>
             {allData[currentIndex]?.correct_option.map((item, index) => Draxzone({ item, index }))}
          </View>
       </View>
       <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-around', width:'100%', marginBottom:20}}>
           <DraxList
              data={allData[currentIndex]?.options}
              renderItemContent={TouchDrag}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.toString()}
              numColumns={3}
              ItemSeparatorComponent={FlatListItemSeparator}
              scrollEnabled={true}
           />
       </View>
    </DraxProvider>
 : <Text>Sorry This Qustion not have type</Text> }
```

the result is executed as follows:
[I tried to drag and drop components, the results are like in steps 2 and 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMkXs.jpg)

while the result I want is as follows: [Text on Dropzone follows text on TouchDrag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDhnp.jpg)

after that, I'm also confused to **validate the correct answer** in the order in **correct_option**. not like a quiz that **only uses options from A to E for example**. Honestly this is new to me, and I've been looking for quiz reference resources that use drag and drop in React Native, but I haven't found any results.

if there is something easier to understand, I ask for guidance. I hope that some of my friends here can help with this problem, thank you for your attention and time.

Comment: How did you manage this? I need to manage the same quiz thing in drag and drop layout. Here is my screen 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76320312/how-to-achieve-this-drag-and-drop-layout-in-react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will fix your issue, but here are some suggestions:

1. Try to use unique IDs instead of indexes.
2. DraxView has a `payload` property in which you could pass in the ID and use it accordingly.

Good luck!