# How to achieve this drag and drop layout in react native?

Tags: react-native, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

I wanted to implement drag and drop question-answer layout in react native. I have tried different libraries but have not gotten the desired output. can anyone suggest to me how to achieve this in react native?
[image: Drag and Drop design]

Comment: Have you tried [react-native-drax](https://github.com/nuclearpasta/react-native-drax)?

Comment: yes @PhantomSpooks but it is not working as expected. sometimes it drop layout outside drop box and sometime behave weird

Answer (score 0):

Libraries that provide of the shelf support for drag and drop are a little jittery and not up the mark, i implemented a similar UI by building upon react-native-reanimated 3x.

You can check the documentation at
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/events